# SLF4J: Use XLogger with LocLogger

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

We are currently using CAL10N to localize log messages generated by SLF4J. To do this, we need to use the `LocLogger` class to define a logger for every class.

Few weeks into development, there comes a time where you have a few bug reports with logs attached - they do have nicely logged stack traces (thanks to SLF4J) for exceptions being thrown, but turns out we have a hard time figuring out the flow since since everyone's new to the code and the flow of things keeps changing every other day!

What we need is ENTRY/EXIT logs for every method. I was hoping that SLF4J will provide a way to do that in the least painful and fastest possible way: and ho behold! It certainly does!

The `XLogger` class provides methods that aid in such verbose logging (see [this link](http://www.slf4j.org/extensions.html)), but after looking at the API docs, looks like both `LocLogger` and `XLogger` implement the `Logger` interface.

So the question is (we got to it finally!) - is it possible to use the `LocLogger` with all the localization benefits of CAL10N in peaceful harmony with `XLogger`, that provides all the verbose logging goodies?

Answer (score 0):

No real answer for this yet - worked around it by leveraging a feature of the underlying implementation.

We're using log4j as the implementation under slf4j. The `PatternLayout` supports printing the package name+method name of the origination of the log message with these specifiers: `%C.%M`

So we simply log well-defined strings, `+++` as the first line in every method and `---` just before returning, to a logger for that class.

Solves the purpose, but not a solution to the original question.